# Installing a react native package with Podfile

Tags: ios, react-native, podfile

I'm following instructions here to add a package: https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob
It says to do npm install OR add to Podfile. What I did was

`yarn add rn-fetch-blob`

Then

```
cd ios
pod install
```

Is that correct? I didn't edit the Podfile but somehow it still knew to get the dependency. Output:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing rn-fetch-blob (0.12.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

The Podfile doesn't have any reference to rn-fetch-blob. Can someone explain if I did it right or if I needed to edit the Podfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do **pod install**, it actually looks into your **package.json** dependancies to see what dependency requires pod installation. As you have already added it to node_modules but not in **Podfile**.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using the latest React Native version like 0.60 and above, this process is simply called [Autolinking](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md)

Basically, whenever you add a new library to your package.json as you did for `rn-fetch-blob` and run pod install after adding it, the whole node_modules folder is being scanned thanks to a script file called `native_modules.rb` to find an appropriate podspec file and install what is necessary to install a pod.

This is the definition of how iOS auto-linking works from the community docs:

**Platform iOS**

> The native_modules.rb script required by Podfile gets the package
> metadata from react-native config during install phase and:
>
> Adds dependencies via CocoaPods dev pods (using files from a local
> path). Adds build phase scripts to the App project’s build phase. (see
> examples below) This means that all libraries need to ship a Podspec
> either in the root of their folder or where the Xcode project is.
> Podspec references the native code that your library depends on.